# Top Link Navigation is not supporting link with Long url

Tags: navigation, url

I have main site with Top Navigation Menu created using Site Collection Settings > Navigation (under Look and Feel).

I'm trying to add a long link to navigation links in Site Collection Settings > Navigation (under Look and Feel) > Add Link

The problem is part of url is getting stripped and look like there is limitation in the length of URL allowed.

I'm using SharePoint 2010 Server.

Comment: the url in question is long because 1) the Navigation is linked to a Subsite from a different sharepoint 2007 location 2) the url to the link has paramters required to link to an infopath form

Comment: There must be workaround for this. I'll be exploring(over the weekend) custom url shortning service in SharePoint route and simply pass the shortened url

Comment: Abhi, have you ever found a good solution to this problem? If so, could you share it here?

Comment: @nldev The only response that I had then was highlighting the limitation. Wasn't helpful so I didn't explore further. I'd come up with something in next 3-4 days. Hold on.URL Shortner is last resort.

Answer (score 3):

The URL links in SPS2010 are limited do 255 characters.
Using a shortening URL service is one solution, maybe microsoft should implement this system in the next version of Sharepoint

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure whether the limit applies to your custom link. SharePoint restricts URL length to 255 characters (may be Yes because Navigation Menu is used by SharePoint to add its own links too)

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff919562.aspx#limits